# Stop Scanner while reading Integers or String

Tags: java, input, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read a String and then Integers or Strings using Scanner:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        String[] StringList; 
        Integer[] IntegerList;
        ArrayList<String> auxS = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> auxI = new ArrayList<>();
        String order; int ord=-1;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        order = scan.nextLine();
        //do something with order

        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
            if(scan.hasNextInt()){
                auxI.add(scan.nextInt());
            }
            else if(!scan.nextLine().isEmpty()){
                auxS.add(scan.nextLine());
            }else{ //I've tried using another scan. methods to get to this point
                scan.next();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I first read a String and store it in "order", then I want to keep reading until EOF or user enters "Enter" or anything else non-specific such as "write 'exit' " or something like that.
I've tried using scan.hasNext, hasNextLine, and other combinations involving the last else but none of them worked.
If the input is:

```
>>THIS WILL BE STORED IN ORDER<<
123
321
213
231
312
<enter>
```

I want it to stop when nothing has been entered as in the last line. It is important to store the Integers or Strings in their own ArrayLists, as I use it later and I need to identify the type of each entered data (that's why I use hasNextInt inside the while loop).

Comment: You would have more control using a BufferedReader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, just don't use `.nextLine()`, it is confusing and rarely does what you want. If you want to read entire lines as a single item, update the scanner's delimiter; change it from the default 'any sequence of whitespace' to 'a single newline': `scanner.useDelimiter("\r?\n");` will do that (run that immediately after making a scanner). To read a line, use any of the `.next()` methods (but not `.nextLine()`): Want an int? call `.nextInt()`. Want any string? Call `.next()`, etcetera.

then split up your if/elseif block. An empty line is still a string, just, an empty one:

```
if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    // deal with ints
} else {
   String text = scanner.next();
   if (!text.isEmpty()) {
       // deal with strings
   } else {
       // deal with a blank line
   }
}
```

NB: Once you stop using `.nextLine()`, you don't have to throw out semi-random `.nextLine()` calls to 'clear the buffer' or whatnot. That annoyance just goes away, which is one of the many reasons why you should just forget about nextLine. Generally, for scanners, either use only `.nextLine()`, or don't ever use `.nextLine()`, and things work out much better.

Comment: This works like a charm for Integers. I was testing this out and when I use it to store Strings (a single word) it does not store them always as I want it to.
i.e. if I type "hello" <enter> "hi" <enter> etc. like 10 times, it does not store the 10 words

Comment: @Izanami that's, again, a threading issue, has nothing to do with scanner. Don't use fields when writing handlers like this.